# Trying to Authenticate using CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme with OpenIddict through angular client application

Tags: openiddict

Trying to Authenticate using CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme with OpenIddict through angular client application but cookie not authenticated. does anyone know whats the issue

```
[HttpPost("login")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginRequestDTO model)
        {
            var user = await _context.Users.Where(x => x.Username == model.Username).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if(user == null)
            {
                return Ok(GenericResponse<bool>.Failure("Invalid Username or Password!", Models.Enums.ApiStatusCode.RecordNotFound));
            }
            else
            {
                if(user.Password != model.Password)
                {
                    return Ok(GenericResponse<bool>.Failure("Invalid Username or Password!", Models.Enums.ApiStatusCode.RecordNotFound));
                }
                else
                {
                    var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Username)
                };

                    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));

                    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                }
            }
        }
```

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            //options.LoginPath = "/login";
            options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
            {
                OnRedirectToLogin = (context) =>
                {
                    context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("http://localhost:4200/login" + context.RedirectUri.Split("Login")[1]);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Cookie is not created.